# Generating monthly data from daily CSV files using Apache Spark and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have CSV files with identical columns and a million matching IDs for every day of 2018. Each has 5 columns, excluding the ID.

I want to concatenate the files by month so that each monthly file has the 5 columns * the number of days so January would have 155 named Day1-Col1, Day1-Col2...Day 31-Col5 for example.

Is this something I can do with Apache Spark?

My choice of Spark is because I want to place the data into an AWS Athena dataset and it seems that AWS Glue can do this with Spark SQL queries.

I imagine we'd convert the CSVs to parquet files first and then produce a monthly dataset with this to later be visualised with AWS Quicksight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark separates out the I/O from the processing a bit. So, I'd do the same here in trying to solve this.

First, I'd load your csv files using AWS Glue Catalog OR Spark's native `wholeTextFiles` method.

From there, you can use either AWS Glue's DynamicFrame methods, Spark SQL's DataFrame methods or you can use Spark's RDD functions for data processing. In this case, the bulk of your processing looks to be grouping your data by month based on day of year. Using RDD you can use the `groupBy` method with a custom function that returns the month index based on day of year. Similarly, Spark SQL's Dataframe has a groupBy method as well. Another alternative here would be to iterate through months in a loop and filter the records based on day of year to the month. In some ways the for loop is cleaner and in others it is dirtier. Finally, a 3rd way to do this would be to add a month field to each record in a map. This would allow you to partition your data by month and you'll probably want year as well.

Finally, to write each month back out depends on how you solved the grouping of data. You can use the AWS Glue Catalog to write the files out if you looped or added a month field for partitioning. If you did a groupBy then you'll need to count the rows, `repartition` to the number of rows and then use Spark to write the files.

Comment: Superb answer thank you!

When you mention use of Spark methods, do you mean performing this processing locally vs on AWS?

Comment: I've spent some time getting my head around Spark RDDs to perform this task. To simplify the problem, I've put daily CSV files into their associated monthly folders. Say I wanted to just work in one of these folders, would I still follow this methodology of getting them all into one RDD and then grouping by an ID? Or could I somehow achieve what I want just with a join?